# How use of small blocks allows in description of high frequencies with less cosine terms?

Tags: compression, image-compression, video-compression

I am studying mpeg compression.
Sources-:

https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0506/s0561282.pdf

https://fdocuments.net/document/video-compression-techniques-55849f2b11fba.html

It says this-:

> Another
> disadvantage of DCT is its inability to decompose a broad signal into high and low frequencies at the
> same time. Therefore the use of small blocks allows a description of high frequencies with less cosine terms.

I don't get what it is trying to say. Can you help me here?

Comment: hm, that simply seems incorrect. It's, just like the DFT, an orthogonal base transform, and does the decomposition for all frequencies "at the same time".

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the point being explained here is similar to the advantages of wavelet transforms and more specifically the [constant-Q transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-Q_transform).

When our interest of frequency evaluation is in the log frequency space (as is often the case whenever the sensitivity of interest for a band of frequencies is proportional to the center frequency, which specifically is the Q of any resonator), we need far fewer frequencies to evaluate the frequency response as we go higher in frequency. This makes something like the DFT very inefficient when evaluating over several decades since we will require the number of bins given by the precision of the lowest decade but continue to compute at that resolution for the higher decades where that may no longer be necessary.

This can be explained simply by a typical low pass filter response for an analog filter, and it's graphical utility when viewed on a log-log scale (log magnitude versus log frequency) versus magnitude versus linear frequency. The fact that the presentation on a log scale is so much more useful is a big hint that we needn't be concerned with the same linear resolution for the higher frequencies.